# Sending mail from Android app gives "less secure app" error

Tags: android, email, gmail

I use Android Studio and this library; https://github.com/yesidlazaro/GmailBackground .

And i am trying send e-mail from my android application. But whenever i am trying to send e-mail from Gmail account, it does not work. Because google pins my app as "less secure app" and blocks it.

I had to allow less secure app from security setting from gmail. But i do not want to do this. How can i solve this problem? make my app not to be less secure app?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download jar files and paste in you libs folder: [link to download](https://code.google.com/archive/p/javamail-android/downloads)
2. Create a **SendMail.java**

   ```
    public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    private Context context;
    private Session session;

   //Information to send email
   private String email;
   private String subject;
   private String message;

   private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
   //Send button


   //Progressdialog to show while sending email
   private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

   //Class Constructor
   public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String message){
       //Initializing variables
       this.context = context;
       this.email = email;
       this.subject = subject;
       this.message = message;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       //Showing progress dialog while sending email
       progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Sending message","Please wait...",false,false);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
       super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
       //Dismissing the progress dialog
       progressDialog.dismiss();
       //Showing a success message
       Toast.makeText(context,"Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       //Creating properties
       Properties props = new Properties();

       //Configuring properties for gmail
       //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
       props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
       props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
       props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
       props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
       props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

       //Creating a new session
       session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
               new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                   //Authenticating the password
                   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                       return new PasswordAuthentication("abc@gmail.com", "password");
                   }
               });

       try {
           //Creating MimeMessage object
           MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

           //Setting sender address
           mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
           //Adding receiver
           mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
           //Adding subject
           mm.setSubject(subject);
           //Adding message
           mm.setText(message);

           //Sending email
           Transport.send(mm);

       } catch (MessagingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
   }}
   ```
3. Then in your **MainActivity.java**:

   ```
       //Creating SendMail object
       SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email_id, fullname, message);

       //Executing sendmail to send email
       sm.execute();
   ```
4. Enable the less secure apps using this [link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

Comment: Can i do this task without enabling the less secure app?

Comment: I don't think Google will allow that. I also tried without enabling but didn't worked. But after enabling it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps

1.Go to gmail
2.settings
3.security
4.enable less secure apps